# How to use a C API in Java? JNI?

Tags: java, c, api, java-native-interface, native

I'm building a J2EE project, in which I would like to use an API which is only available in C.
I was thinking of using JNI to do so, but after a quick look at [this tutorial](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jni/html/start.html), it looks that I in order to use JNI, I need to have the source code (.c files) to compile some kind of "JNI library".

In my case, the API only comports the .h with the signature of all the methods, and the already compiled .dll (or .so).

How could I do this?

Thank you!

Comment: http://cnd.netbeans.org/docs/jni/nb6-linux/beginning-jni-linux.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[JNA](https://github.com/java-native-access/jna) is a JNI-based library that allows calling normal C functions without needing a JNI-specific wrapper for each one.

Comment: I was looking at the JNA option, but the problem I am having is that a lot of data structure that are used are not known. The only information I have in my api.h concerning them is this: "typedef struct my_data_structure my_data_structure ; ///< A handle on my data object". Can I still use JNA?

Comment: That depends: if you only get passed pointers to those types, you should be fine (and simply treat them like you would `void*`). You you need to manipulate them, then you'll be out of luck, no matter which language/API you use.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [JNA](http://jna.java.net/). It allows you to use the .DLL directly. All you need to do is write a Java interface with the same functions you need from the .DLL.

Comment: I was looking at the JNA option, but the problem I am having is that a lot of data structure that are used are not known. The only information I have in my api.h concerning them is this: "typedef struct my_data_structure my_data_structure ; ///< A handle on my data object". Can I still use JNA?

Answer (score 0):

Create a small C wrapper for the native library, compile this to a .dll/.so.

For each needed function in the existing C api, create one JNI-compliant C function which simply calls the real API.

Comment: JNA should make away with the need for such wrappers.

Answer (score 0):

JNI offers a pretty low level API for interfacing your Java code with native code. If you are OK with shelling out money, [Jinvoke](http://www.jinvoke.com/) looks like a pretty good alternative which doesn't require you to write any C/C++ code. The plus here is that you get full paid support. If you don't require it, you can go with JNA. Anything but JNI IMO...